# SwiftUI login page show and hide based on login status

Tags: swiftui

Hi I have written an app using storyboards and decided to look at writing it in SwiftUI.  So far so good.  When it comes to showing (or not showing the login page) based on the users logged in status what is the best way to achieve this?  Most examples just show the login page but never do checks if the user is already logged in.

Comment: Example here [SwiftUI authentication view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61152208/12299030)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can use UserDefaults to check if the user already logged in or not. Or you can use Core Data to keep your record.

This is an example code using UserDefaults:

1. If the user has logged in, you can declare this when user has
   entered the login data and enter

   ```
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   defaults.setValue(true, forKey: "skipTutorialPages")
   defaults.synchronize()
   ```
2. In the AppDelegate, add this to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

   ```
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   let skipTutorialPages = defaults.bool(forKey: "skipLoginPages")

   if skipLoginPages
   {
      // Skip to your login pages          
   }
   ```